# How do you force a response for a RequestMapping to use the AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, atom-feed

Our Spring 3.1 application uses message converters in the following manner:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
     ....
     ....
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" name="objectMapper"/>
```

In one of my controllers, I have a RequestMapping as such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pathFoo", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Feed getFooAtomXML(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
```

but it seems that unless I specify a request header Accept=application/atom+xml, the response comes back as JSON instead of XML.  How can I configure the application so that the AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter is used at this mapping, regardless of whether the request header is present?

Would I need to rely on a ViewResolver?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` bean goes through your list of `HttpMessageConverter` beans in declared order.

It first calls the `canWrite(Class, MediaType)` method on each `HttpMessageConverter` and uses the first one that returns `true`.

Without providing the `Accept` header as `application/atom+xml`, the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` will return `true` first before the `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter` has a chance to. This happens for two reasons.

1. If no `Accept` header is provided, Spring considers all `MediaType`s as acceptable.
2. `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` accepts the `application/json` content-type

This is because `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` is implemented as

```
@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return (this.objectMapper.canSerialize(clazz) && canWrite(mediaType));
         // ^ will pretty much always return true    ^ application/json
}
```

So since the acceptable media types include everything, the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` will be able to produce a response and Spring will choose it.

To change this either change the order of beans

```
<property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="writeAcceptCharset" value="false"/>
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.feed.AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

Or provide an `Accept` header as the HTTP specification specifies.

Or move to Spring 3.2 which uses `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` instead of `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` (which is deprecated), but also registers the `AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter` before the `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` by default.